# How to start lookahead from nearst match to the lookbehind value?

Tags: java, regex

String :

```
 http://example.com/400px/123123.jpg
```

I want to replace `400` with a custom value.

My regex `(?<=/)(.*)(?=px/)` will match `/example.com/400`.

**Question**: how can I start the matcher just from the last slash before `px/` is matched?

Comment: `(?<=\/)([^\/]*)(?=px\/)`

Comment: Can you string look like `http://example.com/400px/fpx/123123.jpg`? Also note that you do not need any lookarounds here, you can use `replaceFirst("/\\d+px/", "/" + newValue + "px/")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the part you need to replace starts with digits followed with `px`, you can use

```
.replaceFirst("/\\d+px/", "/" + newValue + "px/")
```

Note that you do not need any lookarounds here.

The pattern matches

- `/` - a `/`
- `\\d+`  - 1 or more digits (thanks to this, `/TEXT_HERE_px/` won't get matched)
- `px/` - a substring `px/`.

Visualization:

[image]

The `replaceFirst` will only match the first occurrence (since you intend to replace once only).

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/X4Hd1A):

```
String s ="http://example.com/mpx/400px/123123.jpg";
String newValue = "600";
String res = s.replaceFirst("/\\d+px/", "/" + newValue + "px/");
System.out.println(res); // => http://example.com/mpx/600px/123123.jpg
```

Comment: How did you create this nice visualization?

Comment: At [Regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/). I had to remove the backslashes in the Paint though since the regex flavor accepted is JavaScript only.

Answer (score 1):

Since the match is starts from the first `/` at the beginning of the string you can't use non-greedy regex like `.*?`, so what you can do is something like this

```
(?<=\/)[^\/]*(?=px\/)
```

Where `[^\/]` matches - single character not `/`

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/nB4nZ3/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Actually, you'd want `[^/]*?` here, but it is insignificant.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : yup you are right ... `\d+` is enough :)

Comment: I noticed that after posting this comment :) Actually, I also believe no lookarounds should be used when you do not have to, and `replaceFirst` should have been mentioned, so I posted an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : yup , you are right ... you are provided detailed answer +1 :)